# how to get TradingView "Technical Analysis Summary" buy sell indicator in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to use the TradingView "Technical Analysis Summary" buy sell indicator in a Pine Script strategy for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Search “Technical Ratings” by TradingView in the built in indicators. They have the pine script code for you"
Thanks to https://www.reddit.com/user/theyardbirdswereOK/

https://www.reddit.com/r/pinescript/comments/op0mq6/how_to_get_technical_analysis_summary_buy_sell/